# Calculate quarterly Value from Month values on data.table

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate-functions, lapply

In R I have a data.table  called Table_A with 100 variables/ columns and 100 observations, this information is time ordered by month and need to get a new data.table Table_B with all variables from table_A converted in quarterly data (suming months)

Quarter variable name  in Table_A is Quater_var

To solve that I thought to use lapply function in the following way.

Y tried the following solution but no I was no luck

```
Table_B <-Table_A[ , lapply(.SD, sum), by = Quarter_var, .SDcols= cols]

Error in `[.tbl_df`(Tabla_A, , lapply(.SD, sum), by = Quarter_var,  : 
  unused arguments (by = Quarter_variable, .SDcols = cols)
```

Tabla_A looks something like the following.

```
Monnths Quarter_var var1  var2  var3    var3      ....var100
abr-09  2009-Q2     0.1   1660  0.0001  511118.79     ...
may-09  2009-Q2     441   2573  0.1714  497271.12     ...
jun-09  2009-Q2     331   3176  0.1042  522017.26
jul-09  2009-Q3     0.1   1862  0.0001  581255.35
```

Comment: What is `class(Table_A)`? It looks like `Table_A` is not a "data.table" but a "tibble"

Comment: Have you `setDT(Table_A)`?

Comment: @Aurèle you are right I forgot to set Table A as data.table